# String comparison failing in bash

Tags: bash

I'm attempting to loop through an array of strings, and do something a little different with one of the values.  The string comparison fails on every element.

```
arr[0]='red'
arr[1]='blue'
arr[2]='yellow'
arr[3]='green'

## now loop through the above array
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
        if [ "$i"="green" ];
        then
                echo "i('$i') is equal to green"
        else
                echo "i('$i') is not equal to green"
        fi

done
```

I've also tried (with the same result):

```
if [ "$i"='green' ];
```

and

```
if [ $i='green' ];
```

and

```
if [ $i="green" ];
```

Output of each of the above:

```
i('red') is equal to green
i('blue') is equal to green
i('yellow') is equal to green
i('green') is equal to green
```

What am I doing wrong with the comparison?

Comment: I see that four people have marked this for closure.   There are also four upvotes, so clearly others think it is on-topic.   Could someone please instruct me where questions of this nature belong?  There is a `/bash` tag so I assumed this was acceptable use of the sub.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Missing whitespace.

`[ $i="green" ]` means `[ -n $i=green ]`

you need

```
[ "$i" = green ]
```

or even

```
[ green = "$i" ]
```

which works even for `i=-n`.

If you don't need portability to other shells, you can use double square brackets in bash.

```
[[ $i = green ]]
```

Quotes are not needed (in fact, on the right hand side they have a special meaning - they prevent expansion). You can use `==` instead of `=`, too.

Comment: Should that be `[ "$i" = "green" ]`?   (**EDIT**, just tested - it works fine without quotes around green.)

Comment: @acoder: no need to quote `green`, there are no special characters.

Comment: Better to do `[ green = "$i" ]`. That avoids errors if `i` contains something like `-n`. This is a good general practice, because that can make some shells choke. (This is the reason why you'll sometimes see `[ "x$a" = "x$b" ]`.) Bash is a bit smarter about this, but I don't know if it's smarter when using single `[ ... ]` as opposed to `[[ ... ]]`.

Comment: @dubiousjim - seconded. it's *always* better to lead with the known value.

Comment: @dubiousjim Yes, bash is smarter.  `[[ $i = green ]]` works correctly even unquoted with any `-n` or similar. There is no word-splitting inside `[[ ... ]]` in bash.

Comment: @choroba As this question is tagged bash. Please change to the safer `[[ ... ]]`

Answer (score 5):

You need space around the `=` comparison operator:

```
if [ "$i" = "green" ];
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason you need spaces around the `=` is that the `[` and `test` commands do different things depending on how many arguments you pass. When you only pass a single argument (`[ "$i"=green ]`), then the result is true if the string is non-empty.

Your code and your output do not match: given the code you posted, every colour should result in `i('colour') is equal to green`

Comment: ref: [POSIX specification for the `test` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128)

Comment: Fixed type-o in question (your second paragraph).

Answer (score 2):

```
[ green = "$i" ]
printf "( '%s' ) is %.$?0sequal to green.\n" "$i" "not "
```

...would also work.

Comment: Cool stuff. Care sharing how does `%.$?0s` (if I got the magic right) work?

Comment: Ah, found it: ["Field and printing modifiers"](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf) - The dot: Together with a field width, the field is not expanded when the text is longer, the text is truncated instead. `"%.s"` is an undocumented equivalent for `"%.0s"`, which will force a field width of zero, effectively hiding the field from output.

Comment: @h.j.k - `$?` expands to the `[ test ]` command's return - which is generally `1` or `0`. It might also be `2` or something else, but in those cases it's gonna let you know on stderr anyway. So when the command expands when `green = "$i"` it is `printf "... %.00s"` and when it doesn't it is `printf "... %.10s"` which tells `printf` it can use at maximum either 0 or 10 characters from its second argument.